# Is there any way to revert OpenCV2.4.11 after installing OpenCV3?

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi, opencv3.0

i've install OpenCV2.4.11 in my raspberry-pi, and few days ago i installed OpenCV3. There is no problem with the OpenCV3, but now i want to use back OpenCV2.4.11.

> is there any way to use OpenCV2.4.11 instead of OpenCV3 without uninstall them?

[i followed this tutorial when installing OpenCV3](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/)

when i first use OpenCV3, i made no changes at my cmakelists.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install OpenCV 2.4.11 to a separate location, say `/home/your_username/opencv_2.4.11` with CMake option

```
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/your_username/opencv_2.4.11
```

To build your project with OpenCV 2.4.11, add

```
set(OpenCV_DIR /home/your_username/opencv_2.4.11/share/OpenCV)
```

to your `CMakeLists.txt`, after `project(projName)`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, now i can work with both